# In Laravel email sending issue.?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am trying to send email using laravel framework,but I can't.Actually when I put my code and trying to run on wamp server.
I got this error.

```
 InvalidArgumentException in FileViewFinder.php line 137: View [emailconfirm] not found.
```

My Route code:

```
Route::get('sendemail','admin\LoginController@sendemail');
```

MY Controller code:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\admin;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Validator;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use Hash;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Input;
use Mail;
use App\Mail\Reminder;

 public function sendemail(Request $request)
{
     $postsite1234 = $request->all();

     $email = $postsite1234['email'];   

    $to_email = 'bdt.svk@gmail.com';



        Mail::send('emailconfirm',['name' => 'yuven'], function ($message){
         $message->to($to_email,'vijay')
                 ->subject('code');
         $message->from('vijay@app.com', 'vijay');


    });


}
```

Can I send email using wamp server in localhost.? Is that work? please help If you can.

Comment: As the error states, do you have the view `emailconfirm` present in your `views` directory?

Comment: no but i just made and still get this error

Comment: Can you share the exact path and name of the view file?

Comment: thats my url : http://localhost/demohotel/public/admin/account-confirmation      where i made email balde..and its calling by ajax code and ajax url is :url : '<?= URL::to('sendemail')?>', then route as per i already send

Comment: Let me be specific. Do you have a file `emailconfirm.blade.php` in your `resources/views` directory? If no, then that's the problem you are facing.

Comment: I put this name only in  Mail::send('emailconfirm',['name' => 'yuven'], function ($message). here but my blade name account-confirmation.blade.php. so i change my code   Mail::send('account-confirmation',['name' => 'yuven'], function ($message){
       $message->to($to_email,'vijay')
       ->subject('code');
             $message->from('vijay@app.com', 'vijay');

           
        }); and right now i got View [account-confirmation] not found.this error but account-confirmation is already working blade.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130381/discussion-between-linuxartisan-and-v-jay).

Answer (score 0):

In laravel 5.1 and 5.2

Just setup email configuration in .env file:-

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=example@example.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=******
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

In laravel 4,5
Just setup email configuration in config/mail.php same as above. That means mail_driver,mail_host,mail_port, mail_username, mail_password, mail_encryption

Comment: Ok so You need to change the mail_username and mail_password.

Comment: means I put this code with my gmail ID and gmail password